# Hide a listview and show a button on a onItemClick

Tags: android, listview, button, view

I'm trying to hide a listview, once I click on an item, and later show a button in it place, but inside of the setOnItemClickListener, the listview is not accesible. What can I do?

```
    // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
                            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                    MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_venues,
                                    listItems));
                            // Click event for single list row
                            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter,
                                        View view, int position, long arg) {

                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Button here = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iamhere);
                                    lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
here.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                   
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Osea que andamos por "
                                                    + listItems.get(position),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            });
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `lv` is out of scope for `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg)`.

However, `AdapterView<?>` parameter is actually a reference to containing listview, so you can simply change

```
lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to

```
adapter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```